# Nestjs project - how to validate licenses at build

Tags: nestjs

I have a nest.js project and would like to apply some license checker to all my dependencies at build time like e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-webpack-plugin for webpack to ensure I don't mess up legally

Is there any such option available or do I need to create a webpack config for that purpose only?

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a webpack configuration for this. Typescript's compiler doesn't have this functionality built in, so it's only webpack. [You can rad the docs on using a custom config here](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#webpack-options)